# Why this java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message) error showing on every app on my PC

Tags: react-native

```
error: class, interface, or enum expected
package com.fundmanager;
^
1 error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s

    at makeError (S:\Android\FundManagementApp\fundManager\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at S:\Android\FundManagementApp\fundManager\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (S:\Android\FundManagementApp\fundManager\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (S:\Android\FundManagementApp\fundManager\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I got this error suddenly when I went running build, It is not showing on a specific app, I got this on my two apps at a time. can you please tell me the reason for it happening?

I tried almost all the solutions on the internet but not gotten solve yet.

Comment: No one here can help me to solve it.

Comment: you need to deleted node modal or reinstall npm install and re build your app I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the Java version was the cause. Check the Java version first using 'java -version' in terminal.

Comment: this answer seems incomplete. what specific observations about the Java version would be important to take note of? Why? How would that information be used to solve the problem posed in the question?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34335281)